# Remove row from table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I remove row from tableview cell  I cant remove the cell from table view I don't know why  and when I try to delete never gone from table view please someone tell me how I can delete it one cell from multiple cell I have it. I know I should have var but I did not put it for example var = something

```
class addCartTblVC: UITableViewController {
//MARK: -Variables
var coreDataVariables = GetCoreDataVariables()

//MARK: -ViewMethords
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.fetchCart()
    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    backItem.title = "Back"
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}

//MARK: -tableView dataSource
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return coreDataVariables.result_add_Cart.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cartCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartCell", for: indexPath) as! AddCartTblCell
    let img = coreDataVariables.result_add_Cart[indexPath.row].product_Image!
    let userPhotoString = img
    let imageUrl:URL = URL(string: userPhotoString)!
    let imageData:Data = try! Data(contentsOf: imageUrl)
    // Add photo to a cell as a subview

    if let image = UIImage(data: imageData){
         cartCell.pro_Img.image = image
    }
    cartCell.pro_MRP.text = coreDataVariables.result_add_Cart[indexPath.row].product_Price
    cartCell.pro_Details.text = coreDataVariables.result_add_Cart[indexPath.row].product_Name
    cartCell.pro_Discount.text = coreDataVariables.result_add_Cart[indexPath.row].product_Discount
    if cartCell.pro_Discount.text! == cartCell.pro_MRP.text!{
        cartCell.pro_Discount.isHidden = true
        cartCell.crossView.isHidden = true
    }
    else{
        cartCell.pro_MRP.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        cartCell.pro_Discount.isHidden = false
        cartCell.crossView.isHidden = false
    }
    cartCell.proceedBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cartCell.proceedBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addCartTblVC.ProceedTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cartCell.removeFromCoreDataBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cartCell.removeFromCoreDataBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addCartTblVC.deleteFromCart(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cartCell
}


//MARK: -fetchFunction
func fetchCart(){
    let cart = Add_Cart()
    coreDataVariables.result_add_Cart = cart.fetchCart()!
}

//MARK: -Proceed Action
@IBAction func back(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you follow language style conventions! Here's an article to get you started: https://github.com/linkedin/swift-style-guide

Comment: Unrelated but you will get pretty bad user experience when loading data synchronously from a remote URL in `cellForRow`

Comment: Please only post _relevant_ code. It's disrespectful to people reading your question just to dump a whole file and make them read through it all. Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Before loading table data try to loop on coreDataVariables.result_add_Cart and check for duplicate elements and try to make them single element by multiplying product_Price * n of duplicates and take care of product_Discount also.

your approach should be like this ((this method only for removing duplicates)) :

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
mutating func removeDuplicates() {
    var result = [Element]()
    for value in self {
        if !result.contains(value) {
            result.append(value)
        }
    }
    self = result
}
```

==> Hope not getting negative vote for this answer :D